# How can I create a file within a test and convert it to a HttpContent object?

Tags: c#, .net, unit-testing, testing

I am writing tests to test API responses. I need to test the response for a file upload to a .NET API.

So I need to pass a mock file through my post method as a HttpContent object. How can this be achieved? is there a way to create a file object within the test and convert it to the HttpContent object?

If it helps to know, I am using Xunit testing framework.

Comment: Please, show what have you tried so far

Comment: Actually, I am completley stuck on how to do it. It's been suggested to me to use a bash script to do it. But I am not sure how I would go about implementing that either.

Comment: What content type? `multipart/form-data`? or JSON?

Comment: multipart/form-data. It should be receiving media files (.PNG, .JPG, .MP4 etc etc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume `HttpContent` in the question is for `HttpClient`.

`HttpContent` is an abstract class, which cannot be instantiated. You will need to create one concrete derived class based on your request's content type.

In this case, as per the comment, you can use `MultipartFormDataContent`:

```
var content = new MultipartFormDataContent("your boundary");
var file = File.OpenRead("file path");
content.Add(new StreamContent(file), "name", "fileName");
```

Comment: This is great. Thanks. However, this requires a file in my directory somewhere? Is there a way to do this without having to create a file in my directory?

Comment: Yes, `File.OpenRead` reads an actual file and returns a stream. You could use `new MemoryStream()` to create a stream in memory, and write dummy data to it.